# Show hide payment methods based on selected shipping method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method, payment-method

I would like to hide some payment method and enable another one when I select a specified “Shipping Method" in flexible Shipping plugin form wpdesk.

I have already tried that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'gateway_disable_shipping_326' );
function gateway_disable_shipping_326( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        $chosen_methods  = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
        $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

        if ( isset( $available_gateways['payment_method_cod'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'flat_rate:6' ) ) {
            unset( $available_gateways['payment_method_cod'] );
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways; 
}
```

and this one

```
function my_custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
    $chosen_shipping_rates = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    if ( in_array( 'flat_rate:6', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
        unset( $gateways['payment_method_cod'] );
        endif;
    if ( in_array( 'flat_rate:8', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
        unset( $gateways['payment_method_przelewy24'] );
    endif;
    return $gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'my_custom_available_payment_gateways' );
```

The link to my website: [www.dajati.pl][1]

Comment: Hey Artur, can you share what didn't work about the approaches you tried?

Comment: Hey Zach so payments methods didn't hide when I chose certain delivery methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code example will enable / disable payment gateways based on chosen shipping method.

In this example, we have 3 shipping methods and 3 payment gateways. Each selected shipping method will enable only one different payment gateway.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateways_based_on_chosen_shipping_method' );
function payment_gateways_based_on_chosen_shipping_method( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin) and Not in order pay page
    if( is_admin() ||  is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay') ) 
        return $available_gateways;
     
    // Get chosen shipping methods
    $chosen_shipping_methods = (array) WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

    if ( in_array( 'flat_rate:12', $chosen_shipping_methods ) )
    {
        unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
        unset( $gateways['cod'] );
    }
    elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:14', $chosen_shipping_methods ) )
    {
        unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
        unset( $gateways['paypal'] );
    }
    elseif ( in_array( 'free_shipping:10', $chosen_shipping_methods ) )
    {
        unset( $gateways['cod'] );
        unset( $gateways['paypal'] );
    }

    return $gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> To be able **to get the correct shipping method ID** you can use your browser inspector, this way:
>
> [image]

Comment: You might need to consider adding to the is_admin() conditional regarding the order-pay endpoint. If someone is sent an email with the order for pending payment, it has the potential to remove all available methods. Checking for it looks like this = is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' )

Comment: you start with `$available_gateways` and then use undefined `$gateways`, works after fixing the bug

Answer (score 2):

Since I was looking for solution to this also, and LoicTheAztec's answer were removing all payments, here is a slightly modified working solution.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateways_based_on_chosen_shipping_method' );
function payment_gateways_based_on_chosen_shipping_method( $available_gateways ) {
    // Not in backend (admin) and Not in order pay page
    if( is_admin() ||  is_wc_endpoint_url('order-pay') ) 
        return $available_gateways;
     
    // Get chosen shipping methods
    $chosen_shipping_methods = (array) WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

    if ( in_array( 'flat_rate:12', $chosen_shipping_methods ) )
    {
        unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
        unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
    elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:14', $chosen_shipping_methods ) )
    {
        unset( $available_gateways['bacs'] );
        unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
    }
    elseif ( in_array( 'free_shipping:10', $chosen_shipping_methods ) )
    {
        unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
        unset( $available_gateways['paypal'] );
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

The only difference is that all `$gateways` had to be changed to `$available_gateways`, or vice versa.