# Hide WooCommerce Payment Method Function Disables WordPress nav-menus.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have made hidden the other payment methods if selected COD method (which is flat_rate:5 in my case). I. am using [Show hide payment methods based on selected shipping method in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345129/show-hide-payment-methods-based-on-selected-shipping-method-in-woocommerce/55348064#55348064) answer where I have made some minor edits.

The code works exactly as it should be however, I can't edit menus in "Appearance -> Menus" screen. It seems no problem in front-end.

```
function payment_gateways_based_on_chosen_shipping_method( $gateways ) {
// Get chosen shipping methods
$chosen_shipping_methods = (array) WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

if ( in_array( 'flat_rate:5', $chosen_shipping_methods ) )
{
    unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
    unset( $gateways['iyzico'] );
}

return $gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateways_based_on_chosen_shipping_method' );
```

I am totally confused where is the bug and why it only appears on "Appearence -> Menus" page.

Also [this guy](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/menus-not-showing-up-4/) from WordPress support forum had encounter similar issue with different code but in same filter (woocommerce_available_payment_gateways).

Thank you.

Comment: I have updated my answer code… The answer below from @ZecKa is right and you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because WC()->session is null on backoffice. So you can't call method "get".

You need to check if you are in admin area before execute your code:

```php
function payment_gateways_based_on_chosen_shipping_method( $gateways ) {
  if(is_admin()){
    return $gateways;
  }
  // Get chosen shipping methods
  $chosen_shipping_methods = (array) WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

  if ( in_array( 'flat_rate:5', $chosen_shipping_methods ) ){
    unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
    unset( $gateways['iyzico'] );
  }

  return $gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateways_based_on_chosen_shipping_method' );
```

Comment: Thanks good answer +1… I have updated the original answer thread.