# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null | $chosen_shipping_rates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting the following error on our WP/WC website. This removes certain payment methods from the checkout based on their shipping method. Is this related to a recent update? I've also seen that this could be related to the object cache but I'm a bit stumped without re-writing the function.

Error:

```
An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 746 of the file /xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/functions.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/functions.php:746
```

The code being used:

```
function my_custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
$chosen_shipping_rates = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods', array() );

if ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:252-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:131-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:132-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:133-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:134-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:135-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:150-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:136-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:207-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:137-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:208-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:138-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:215-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:139-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:219-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
    // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
    unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
endif;

return $gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'my_custom_available_payment_gateways' );
```

Comment: Looks like `WC()->session` is null. In this case there is no get mathod. Add a null check and the problem should be gone.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Would you have time to point me in the right direction to do so? I also noticed this method which is similar to mine but looks like it checks whether user is admin and is during the checkout process to stop the function being called when not needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345129/show-hide-payment-methods-based-on-selected-shipping-method-in-woocommerce

Comment: Its just a simple null check lol. But I can do it for you..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And a null check to your code to prevent a function call to the session in case its null:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways' );
function filter_woocommerce_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) {
    $session = WC()->session;

    if ( $session ) {
        $chosen_shipping_rates = $session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods', [] );

        if ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:252-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:131-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:132-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:133-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:134-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:135-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:150-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:136-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:207-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:137-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:208-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:138-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:215-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:139-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        elseif ( in_array( 'betrs_shipping:219-1', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
            // Remove bank transfer payment gateway
            unset( $gateways['sagepayform'] );
        endif;
    }

    return $gateways;
}
```

Comment: That did the job. Thank you mate!